# Is there any plugin or add on for adding a file uploader into the wooCommerce product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a plugin or addon for adding a file uploader into my product page.

As my client is selling something that should require some kind of certificate or evidence, this would request the user to upload the pics or files when they want to add something into the cart.

I've found a solution is to add the meta attribute for the product and then add the file uploader into the product page. But my project leader denied my solution, he wants me to search for some possible plugin or add on first.

What I need to is like, I need to find a plugin or add on which could enable me to add a file uploader on the product page when the customer is placing the order. The file will be included in the order because my client will not directly charge the money from the customer, once my client check that the evidence or certificate is valid, the money could charged and the good could be shipped.

I've done some search and I think just add a meta attribute is easy, but my leader denied this. So I am coming to ask some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a plugin like this https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742

It's a paid plugin though.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is too many plugins (free or paid) are available to customize WooCommerce product page.

But File Upload option may only available in premium plugins.

Can you please check [themehigh's WooCoomerce extra product option](https://www.themehigh.com/product/woocommerce-extra-product-options) plugin?.

I have tried that plugin for one of my client. The options available in product page are File Upload, Text, Hidden, Password, Textarea, Radio, Checkbox, Select, Multi-select, Date picker, Time picker, Heading & Label etc.